# How to remove all marker on the map using mapbox android?

Tags: android, mapbox, marker

I am using the following code to remove all the markers from the map:

```
for (Marker marker : listOfMarkers) {
    mapView.removeMarker(marker);
}
```

But markers are not being removed from the map.

I am using the following library in my project:

```
compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:3.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Can anybody suggest whether mapbox library is sufficient or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MapboxMap#clear()` or `MapboxMap#removeMarker(yourMarker)

Comment: Tried before. But, there is no method called **mapview.clear()** in the following library.

Comment: I wil try this and get back to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not worked. After trying all the solutions, i tried **mapView.removeAllAnnotations()** and worked for me. Anyway thanks for your quick response. Thanks dear.

Comment: mapView? clear() is not on MapView but on MapboxMap class.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to remove all markers from a mapbox object;

```
mapboxMap.removeAnnotations();
```

Comment: It is now deprecated and you should use https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/master/plugin-annotation

Answer (score 0):

`symbolManager.delete(symbol)` using the new mapbox [annotation plugin](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/guides/annotation/).

Answer (score 0):

in v10 It will work

```
pointAnnotationManager?.deleteAll()
```